# Chrome not displaying XML structurally

Tags: xml, api, google-chrome

My API produces application/xml and it worked fine. But ever since I bought my domain and used it for "forward with masking", Chrome is not displaying XML in structured way but it displays the response in plain text in a single line. What can I do to resolve this ?

Comment: What is the sense of structured XML displaying? Why is it bothering you? The reason is probably related to Content-Type header. Check the response headers. It should have `Content-Type: application/xml` in order to make browser output it in a "structured way".

Comment: Structured XML, of course, looks good to eyes and easy to read than plain text.

Comment: Content type is not Content-Type: application/xml but its Content-Type: text/html. And thats what I want to ask, when my response type is in xml, why is it sending the response plain text and why only in chrome ?

Comment: One difference which I see between chrome and Firefox is that the Chrome is trying to load favicon.ico page after all request is processed which has response content type as application/html.